# I need help to debug cells in Mine Sweeper personal project

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, minesweeper

first post here. I'm a newbie, and for my personal Javscript project I'm trying to clone the old Mine Sweeper windows game. In the generating field algorithm I declared this If statement that calculates the previous number, the following and the upwards, downwards and diagonals. Assuming x= bomb number, I used the x+1, x-1 for next and previous. Then x+rowLenght, x-rowLenght for upwards and downwards. Then x+rowLenght +1, x+rowlenght +1, x-rowLenght +1, x-rowLenght-1 for diagonals.

The problems appears when a bomb is placed on the grid border, so I got green cells also in wrong places (after or before).

```
        let gridLenght = Math.sqrt(numbOfCells);
        const cellNumb = Number(singleCell.textContent);       

        if (bombsArray.includes(cellNumb)) {
            //   this adds bombs based on bombsArray generated randomly

           singleCell.classList.add('bomb')

            //  this creates the green cells near the bomb cell

            
        } else if (bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - 1)
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + 1)
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLenght)
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLenght)
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLenght - 1)
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLenght + 1)
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLenght - 1)
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLenght + 1)
        ) {

            singleCell.classList.add('green');
            singleCell.addEventListener('click', function () {
                addGreenPoints()
            })

        }
```

I'm trying to add a specific rule, that reads when a bomb is placed on the border and in that case override the if else statment, or maybe just delete the green cell class.

```
if (bombsArray.includes(cellNumb) == (gridLenght * 10)) {
            singleCell.classList.remove('green');
            console.log("bomb on the right border");
        }
```

But it seems to not be working, likewise the condition is never verificated. I can't figure it out if the problem is in the logic or in the code itself.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Edit: the grid numbers (cellNumb) starts with 1, not 0.

Edit: The Blue Grid:
As a second feature I tried to use the same logic suggested by Trincot (thank you) but to add an outer rim of blue cells representing the farthest indicator of a bomb, they'll give 1 point instead of 3 if you click it. The basic logic works, but I found odd behaviors on borders. It seems that borders numbers generate 2 extra cells in the other border, but I cant find which rule isn't working properly.

```
    let gridLength = Math.sqrt(numbOfCells);
    const cellNumb = Number(singleCell.textContent);

    const atRightSide = cellNumb % gridLength === 0;
    const atLeftSide = (cellNumb - 1) % gridLength === 0;

    const twoRightSide = cellNumb % gridLength === 0 || (cellNumb + 1) 
      % gridLength === 0;
    const twoLeftSide = (cellNumb - 1) % gridLength === 0 || (cellNumb) 
     % gridLength === 2;

    if (bombsArray.includes(cellNumb)) {
        singleCell.classList.add('bomb')

        //  this create green cells

    } else if (!atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - 1)
        || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + 1)
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength)
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength)
        || !atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength - 1)
        || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength + 1)
        || !atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength - 1)
        || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength + 1)
    ) {

        singleCell.classList.add('green');
        singleCell.addEventListener('click', function () {
            addGreenPoints()
        })

         //  this create blue cells (example 55)

    } else if (
        !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - 2)
        // 53
        || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + 2)
        // 57
        //left and right blue cell

        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2))
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2))
        // these are the top/bottom blue cells

        || !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) - 2)
        // ↖↖ Nord-west-west blue cell (33)
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) - 1)
        //  ↖ Nord-west blue cell 34
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) + 1)
        // ↗ Nord-est blue cell 36 
        || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) + 2)
        // ↗↗ Nord-est-est blue cell 37
        || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength + 2)
        // ➡ West blue cell 47
        || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength + 2)
        // ↘ South-est blue cell 67
        || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) + 2)
        // ↘↘ South-est-est blue cell 77
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) + 1)
        // ➡ Est blue cell 76
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) - 1)
        // ⬅ West blue cell 74
        || !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) - 2)
        // ↙↙ South-west-west blue cell 73
        || !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength - 2)
        // ⬅ Est blue cell 63
        || !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength - 2)
        // ⬅ Est blue cell 43

    ) {

        singleCell.classList.add('blue');
        singleCell.addEventListener('click', function () {
            addBluePoints()
        })


    }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript; this will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that the code looks at a cell that is at the other end of the board (because crossing the boundary), use modular logic, as follows:

```
    const atRightSide = (cellNumb + 1) % gridLenght === 0;
    const atLeftSide  = cellNumb % gridLenght === 0;
```

And then:

```
    } else if (!atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - 1)
        || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + 1)
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLenght)
        || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLenght)
        || !atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLenght - 1)
        || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLenght + 1)
        || !atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLenght - 1)
        || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLenght + 1)
    ) {
```

Some other remarks:

- The correct spelling is "length", not "lenght"
- `bombsArray` can better be a Set than an Array

#### Remark

If your numbering of cells does not start with 0, but with 1, then just adapt the definition of the `atLeftSide` and `atRightSide` variables:

```
    const atRightSide = cellNumb % gridLenght === 0;
    const atLeftSide  = cellNumb % gridLenght === 1;
```

Comment: Assume a 10x10 grid with 0 excluded. So at right side would be 10 multiples. Why const atRightSide has the +1 ? I'd think atRightSide would be cellNumb % gridLenght === 0, and atLeftSide (with 11 multiples) would be (cellNumb -1) % gridLenght === 0; am I missing something? Thanks for help <3

Comment: Assume 3x3 grid. First row has numbers 0, 1, 2. Second row has 3, 4, 5. Third row has 6, 7, 8. I assume zero-based indexing as is common practice in programming. If it is different in your case, then please edit your question and mention this specification.

Comment: I'm trying to implement an outer grid outside the green one, and I'm again stuck at declaring the condition to avoid the borders. I tried something like this: but won't work.
        const twoLeftSide = (cellNumb - 2) % gridLength === 0;
        const twoRightSide = (cellNumb + 2) % gridLength === 0;

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are on about.

Comment: My second goal (unfortunately not reached, but I tried my best) is to add another "circle" of cell around the green ones, the blue ones. They'll represent the lowest level of point you can get clicking, and the farthest indicator of a bomb. I tried to add another else if using a similar logic to your prev suggestion, but it seems working strangely. I'll edit my post for more details if you want to check. Thanks a lot for help!